# How to add a multiple linear regression line in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

Just had a quick question about adding a multiple linear regression line in ggplot.  Here's my code so far:

```
data(teengamb, package='faraway')
attach(teengamb)
lmod=lm(gamble~income+sex)
formula=4.041+5.172*income+-21.634*sex
formula_1=append(formula, 4.041, 0)
formula_1_df=data.frame(MLR=formula_1, Participant=c(0:47), sex=append(sex, 0, 0), income=append(income, 0, 0))
formula_1_df %>%
ggplot(aes(Participant, MLR))+geom_point(aes(color=sex))
```

My multiple linear regression line is 4.041 + 5.172*(income) + -21.634*(sex).  How would I add this line to my ggplot?

Also, since `sex` is a binary variable, will I be allowed to add it as a predictor?

I attached a picture of what the graph looks like.

[image: the graph produced from the code]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `formula_1_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Participant, MLR))+geom_point(aes(color=factor(sex)))+
  geom_line(aes(y=MLR,color=factor(sex)))
`

Comment: Not quite but this is good! I just need to add  4.041 + 5.172*(income) + -21.634*(sex) to the line. So not the shock-y graph but the linear graph.

Comment: add `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)`

Comment: @Phil I can't really do that because I have more than 1 predictors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  `formula_1` and `formula` are correct and produce the following graphs, respectively.

[image]

Then add lines:

[image]

For some reason, I was thinking the formula line would be linear but it's actually a shock-y type of line.

Thus, by adding `geom_line(data=data.frame(MLR, Participant), col="purple")`, I get the correct answer which is the shock-y graph.

```
data(teengamb, package='faraway')
attach(teengamb)
lmod=lm(gamble~income+sex)
formula=4.041+5.172*income+-21.634*sex
formula_1=append(formula, 4.041, 0)
formula_1_df=data.frame(MLR=formula_1, Participant=c(0:47), sex=append(sex, 0, 0), income=append(income, 0, 0))
formula_1_df %>%
ggplot(aes(Participant, MLR))+geom_point(aes(color=sex))+geom_line(data=data.frame(MLR, Participant), col="purple")
```

Gives me:

[image]

Which *I think* is the correct answer.